# javascript moving cloned nodes in a table

Tags: javascript

I have a table:

```
id1 || desc-name - 1
id2 || desc-name - 2
id3 || desc-name - 3
id4 || desc-name - 4
id5 || desc-name - 5
```

I would like to clone  row 3 and 4 and flip them:

```
id1 || desc-name - 1
id2 || desc-name - 2
id4 || desc-name - 4
id3 || desc-name - 3
id5 || desc-name - 5
```

I have to use clone methodologies rather than jQuery.

I have figured out how to clone the rows and delete the current rows out of the table, however, I can't figure out how to replace the cloned rows in the right position?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to use clone methodologies"?  You really can't use JQuery at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have jQuery in your project all, even though you are using a different methodology? If so, I believe that moving the row is as easy as calling

```
$('#id3').insertAfter($('#id4'));
```

I'm not sure how to do this is plain old JS, but I figured I would post this **in case** jQuery was an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
row.parentNode.insertBefore(row, row.previousElementSibling);
```

Note: `previousElementSibling` is not implemented in older versions of IE (IE8 and below).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/8AKxZ/

---

Just for comparison, the jQuery equivalent is this:

```
$(row).insertBefore($(row).prev());
```